# How to get notified whenever a certain field changes on any item inside an ObservableCollection?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, observablecollection, propertychanged

```
public ObservableCollection<Activity> activities = 
    new ObservableCollection<Activity> { };

public class Activity{
    public ObservableCollection<Event> Events { get; set; }
}

public class Event : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _Status;
    public int Status
    {
        get { return _Status; }
        set 
        {
            _Status = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Status");
        } 
    }
}
```

Supposing that `Status` property of an `Event` was changed. `OnPropertyChanged("Status")` will be called, right?

But i want that collection `activities` be notified too about this `Event` change.

Any way to do it??

**Trying to resume:** 
This scenario is described above. 
Imagine some change in some Event.
I need that the collection activities, that has inside of it the parent activity of this event, be notified about this change... so i can call a method to update the event showed in some place of my interface. And in this interface is just visible the activities collection.

*It is because of this that the collection must also be notified.*

Comment: Suppose it were notified. What would it do as a result? What do you actually want to happen? If you want to keep the collection sorted, try this [ObservableSortedList<T>](https://bitbucket.org/rstarkov/wpfcrutches/src/tip/ObservableSortedList.cs).

Comment: I don't want to keep the collection sorted. I just want it. It's specific to my system.

Comment: Then you don't need to notify the collection of the Status change. Seriously.

Comment: In some moment of this system i need to know when some change happens in some event, in this activities collection, to start some method because in determinated moment i just see the activities collection.

Comment: Of course I need... (: I think that you cannot say that i don't need to notify the collection.

Comment: It's a specificity of my system. If an event change then your parent activity is notified (and it changes... any way).

Comment: So you want to notify the parent **Activity**, not the _collection_! Now I understand :)

Comment: No, i really need to notify the collection. The parent activity is inside it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12807/discussion-between-richard-and-romkyns)

Comment: I feel like if Activity implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` and the observable collection inside Activity raised `OnPropertyChanged` everything will be solved.  But then again, I could be misinterpreting the question.

Comment: I tried it. But the i change and Event object the collection is not notified.

Comment: I really want to solve this problem :(

Answer (score 0):

You do not - .net collections do not care of the change of an item in them, only of a change in the collection.

Whoever listens to events in the colection has to subscribe / unsubscibe to PropertyChanged on the items he is interested in.

Answer (score 0):

It's a pain, and there's nothing built-in that will do this for you.

When I needed to do this, I just subscribed to the CollectionChanged event of the ObservableCollection and manually managed my subscribing and unsubscribing to the contained items' PropertyChanged events. Do note that unsubscribing to removed items is important! Otherwise you can really get yourself in trouble with your event subscriptions stopping garbage collection of removed items.

I suppose it's possible to build a wrapper or your own collection class that will sit around a collection and mediate the add/remove in order to subscribe/unsubscribe to property changed events. It didn't seem worth the effort.

As for why you would want to do this, the most basic example is that you have a variable set of items and you need to know whether the set is dirty/needs saving. If your save action operates on the whole set, then having to watch all of the items feels like the wrong thing. There are, I'm sure, other reasons why this would seem like a cleaner solution.

Comment: Can you help me in this? i mean to find the best solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this just creating a static Action:

```
public class Event{
    public static Action OnChanged;
}
```

Basically, i call this everytime i need to do some change based on some event change.

```
    private StatusMode _Status;
    [DataMember(Name = "Status")]
    public StatusMode Status
    {
        get { return _Status; }
        set 
        {
            _Status = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Status");
            if (OnChanged != null)
            {
                OnChanged();
            }
        } 
    }
```

Using:

```
Event.OnChanged = UpdateContent;

public void UpdateContent()
{
//do something
}
```